# MQTT client connectionLost do not work after reconnect to broker

Tags: java, mqtt, broker

I'm newbie in MQTT. I try to reconnect to broker when the client lost connection. This is my function:

```
@Override
public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    reconnectStatus = 0;

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(reconnectRunnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // reconnect every 5s

    System.out.println(cause);
}
```

And this is function to reconnect:

```
// reconnect to the broker
Runnable reconnectRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       if(reconnectStatus == 1) {
           System.out.println("Stop runnable!");
           executor.shutdown();
           return;
       } else {
           init();
       }
    }
};
```

It's working fine at the firs time when broker restart. However, this `connectionLost()` trigger does not work at the second time I restart the broker.
How can I fix it? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for extra code for automatic reconnect if you use [this mqtt client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3)

You can specify reconnect and clean session option in `MqttConnectOptions` while creating `MqttClient`.

Sample code:

```
public void initClinet(){
    MqttClient client=new MqttClient("server address", MqttClient.generateClientId());
    client.setCallback(new MyListener());
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    options.setCleanSession(true);
    options.setUserName("username");
    options.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
    options.setKeepAliveInterval(10);
    options.setCleanSession(false);
    client.connect(options);
    client.subscribe("channelname");    
}
```

Comment: FYI, unrelated to your answer, you have setCleanSession(true) and setCleanSession(false).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was using `Mqttclient.reconnect()`.